# Can we use Conga Composer Application with Force.com sites?

Tags: force.com-sites, conga

I am having a requirement of sending Conga generated document to Force.com sites.
Is it possible?
Can someone pls share a link of any documentation,so that it would be helpful for me to fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Conga Composer requires an authenticated user as it is a named user license model.  Some clients have setup solutions using Force.com Sites where the sites user could invoke a workflow rule, then Conga Composer would be initiated through an outbound message action tied to a Salesforce Workflow rule.